# To what is $f^{-1}(G_2)$ equal??

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\displaystyle{f: G_1 \rightarrow G_2}$, then $\displaystyle{f^{-1}: G_2 \rightarrow G_1}$, right??

Could you tell me which set is $$f^{-1}(G_2)$$?? Is it the set $G_1$??

Answer (score 3):

The notation here is for the pre-image of the function $f$. That is
$$f^{-1}(G_2) = \{ g \in G_1 \;|\; f(g) \in G_2\}$$

Since $f \colon G_1 \to G_2$ is a function, all $g \in G_1$ satisfy the relevant property, so $f^{-1}(G_2) = G_1$.

Note also that for $f^{-1} \colon G_2 \to G_1$ to be a *function*, $f$ itself needs to be a bijection (i.e. one-to-one and onto). In this case, $f^{-1}(G_2)$ is the image of the function $f^{-1}$, which happens to also be $G_1$. If $f$ is not a bijection and $X \subset G_2$, then $f^{-1}(X)$ needs to be interpreted as the pre-image (a set).

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add that $f^{-1}$ can also mean the inverse function $f^{-1}\colon G_2\to G_1$, *provided that function exists*. This seems to be part of the OP's confusion.

Comment: For sure. I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $f: G_1 \to G_2$ that implies that $f$ is a function, which means that every element in $G_1$ has an image in $G_2$. However, that does not necesarily mean that every element in $G_2$ has an original.

The function $f^{-1}$ is only properly defined for the subset of $G_2$ that does have an original. The consequence is that $f^{-1}(G_2)=G_1$.
But you cannot say that $f^{-1}:G_2 \to G_1$ is a function as long as you do not know that each element in $G_2$ is "reachable" by $f$ and also that each of those originals only has 1 image.

Properly, you can only write: $f^{-1}: f^{-1}(G_2) \to G_2$.
This is the function that maps each element that does have an original to its original. And to do that you also need that each of those images only has 1 original.

Comment: I see no reason to label your $f^{-1}: f^{-1}(G_2) \to G_1$ as $f^{-1}$ as this is the identity map and has very little to do with $f$.